# Django: ManyToMany Population

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my first Django application and looking to create a script to populate data to my models for testing purposes—similarly to that done when working through Tango with Django. (http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models.html#creating-a-population-script)

I'm aware on how to populate most model fields, but getting caught up on populating ManyToMany fields. What's the best way to go about this?

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Genre(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


class Artist(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False)
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='artist_photos', blank=True)
  logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='artist_logos', blank=True)
  genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
  twitter = models.URLField(blank=True)
  facebook = models.URLField(blank=True)
  instagram = models.URLField(blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Venue(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False)
  logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='venue_logos', blank=True)
  capacity = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  zip_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  website = models.URLField(blank=True)
  twitter = models.URLField(blank=True)
  facebook = models.URLField(blank=True)
  instagram = models.URLField(blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Show(models.Model):
  venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
  date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
  attendance = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
  bands = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
```

### populate.py

```
import os

def populate():
  # Population of genres
  hardcore = add_genre('hardcore')
  poppunk = add_genre('pop-punk')
  indie = add_genre('indie')
  rock = add_genre('rock')
  pop = add_genre('pop')
  rnb = add_genre('rnb')
  hiphop = add_genre('hip-hop')

  # Population of venues
  chain_reaction = add_venue(name='Chain Reaction', cap=400)
  the_observatory = add_venue(name='The Observatory', cap=1500)
  the_glasshouse = add_venue(name='The Glasshouse', cap=700)

  # Population or artists 
  justin_timberlake = add_artist(name='Justin Timberlake', ??????)


def add_genre(name):
  g = Genre.objects.get_or_create(name=name)

def add_venue(name, cap):
  v = Venue.objects.get_or_create(name=name, capacity=cap)

def add_artist(name, genres):
  a = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print 'GOING...'
  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'artist_database.settings')
  from artistdb.models import Genre, Venue, Artist
  populate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a ManyToMany manager's add method has the ability to take multiple models or ids:

```
ids_list = [1,2,3]
artist.genre.add(*ids_list) # or
artist.genre.add(1,2,3)
```

or

```
genres_queryset = Genre.objects.filter(name__in=[genres])
artist.genre.add(*genres_queryset)
```

so you could rewrite your method:

```
def add_artist(name, genres):
  a, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
  a.genre.add(*Genre.objects.filter(name__in=[genres]))
```

Comment: How would I format the `genres` input. As of right now I am getting empty lists when running `genres_queryset`. This is what I have currently: `john_coltrane = add_artist(name='John Coltrane', genres=['jazz', 'experimental'])`

Comment: Never mind. I was passing the `genres` argument as a list therefor I don't need `[genres]` argument in filter, but rather `genres`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the Genres in your add_artist function, pass in the genres as a list and add them to the many to many field like so:

```
def add_artist(name, genres):
  a, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
  for genre in genres:
     a.add(genre)
```

More information in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: thanks for reaching out. I'm running into the following issue: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate.py", line 37, in <module>
    populate()
  File "populate.py", line 19, in populate
    justin_timberlake = add_artist(name='Justin Timberlake', genres=['rnb', 'pop'])
  File "populate.py", line 31, in add_artist
    a.add(genre)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: Ah sorry about that, fixed it now. The error is because of the `get_or_create` method that returns a `tuple` of the form `(object, created)` where `created` is `True` if the object was created, otherwise if it was already there created is `False`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for more info on the `get_or_create` method

Answer (score 1):

You should read the docs on [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) as you don't need to do this with a script. Adding a Many to Many field called `m2m` to the example from the docs looks like:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
      "m2m": [1,2]
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
      "m2m": [1,2]
    }
  }
]
```

You'll see that the m2m field just takes a list of primary keys as an argument.